# Placing a fixed element above browser's scrollbar

Tags: css, google-chrome, scrollbar

Basically, I want to show an overlay div that covers everything on the page, including the scroll-bars.

Is it possible for a fixed element to appear above the page's scroll-bars ? I tried setting the z-index of the scroll-bars to -1, but apparently doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, html elements cannot render over the browser chrome (scroll bars, etc).

For more information on how pages are rendered, read this article [Web Browser Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_browser_engine)

Also with Z-index, the lower numbers are behind objects with higher numbers. More or less, for more detail see the [CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index)

Answer (score 7):

It's not possible, but a simple alternative is to turn off the scrollbars on the body element and introduce them in an inner element instead.

css:

```
/* these three elements are sized to fit the screen */
html, body, .content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-y: hidden; /* no scrollbars on the body */
}
/* this element gets the scrollbars */
.content-wrapper {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class='content-wrapper'>
            <!-- put your content here -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now your page will look exactly the same as before, but you can put elements on top of the scrollbar.

Here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/e4azdn93/).

Comment: how to make the `content-wrapper` staticly at 100% of the screen `width` or `height` ? above code not work for me, `chrome 70`

Comment: I also added `height: 100vh` to .content-wrapper to fix its size to the screen's height.