# z-index stacking context — child overlap parent w/ overflow: hidden?

Tags: css, z-index

What's the best way to achieve this:

I have two elements, both absolutely positioned and I want the child to overlap horizontally, even though its parent has overflow-x: hidden.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kirkbross/h1bzyz0o/8/)

```
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:1;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 300px;
  overflow-y:auto;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  width: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
}
.child {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:2;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 30px;
  left: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #555;
  color: white
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16365320/3597276

Answer (score 0):

Add a third div that is a parent of both. Position both items absolutely within the outer parent.

```
<div class="outer-parent">
  <div class="parent">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```